# Networking Issues after vmware p 2 v

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-vcenter, physical-to-virtual

I recently migrated a windows 2003 physical machine to virtual, I've installed vm tools, and reconfigured the nic to use the vmxnet 2 adapter, and changed that to the E1000 nic as a troubleshooting step but I am getting the following error :

the identification of the computer cannot be changed because - networking is not installed or is not properly configured.

I can ping the server and back to other hosts, but cannot rename or remove from the domain, as the option is greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

The Client didn't install the client for microsoft networks, once this was added to the nic it worked and the option was no longer grayed out.